# file get content use which ip_address

Tags: php, function, ip

I want to get the content of the page by PHP (`file_get_content`), but it is protected by specified IP addresses that have the permit to get into this page.

Which IP address should I give the permit to get into this protected page to make this function work?

My personal IP address or my site IP address (which should I include the function)?

Answer (score 0):

When a script on ServerA uses `file_get_contents()` to access ServerB, the address that ServerB sees is ServerA's address, not the address of the web client. The web client talks to ServerA, and ServerA talks to ServerB. The fact that the original request came from a web client is not visible to ServerB.

So you should put ServerA's address in the permission list.

Comment: ok how i can get server ip i put my site on infinityfree host

Comment: Use `nslookup` to look up the IP address of your webserver hostname.

Comment: when i put my ip it work when i put my site ip and get into file get content page it doesn't work

Comment: The web hosting service might have a proxy server that's changing the IP. Take a look at https://www.ipify.org/ for an API you can use to find out the public IP. But it's also possible that they have a load balancer so it changes dynamically, which could make this difficult. You should talk to your hosting service.